# Wordapp not closing in Thread or Parallel process

Tags: c#, multithreading

the code below normally works and word is opened and closed after saving a docx/doc to pdf however when using the following code in a thread or Parallel for loop it does not, any have any ideas? I have provided all the code below.

this is the code when used in a function works fine.

```
     wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(sourceFile, false);
        wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(destFile, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
        object saveOption = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
        object originalFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat;
        object routeDocument = false;


        if (wordDocument != null)
            ((_Document)wordDocument).Close(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);

        if (wordApp != null)
            ((_Application)wordApp).Quit(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);

        wordDocument = null;
        wordApp = null;
```

Below is the Parallel.For code which i tried to call the code above:

```
   Parallel.For(1, Int32.Parse(iNrOfThreads.Text), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Int32.Parse(iNrOfThreads.Text) }, i =>                 
            {
                fileName = fileNameLarge + i.ToString() + ".doc";
                fileName2 = fileNameLarge + i.ToString() + ".pdf";
                string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
                string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName2);

                GeneratePDFWithProgressWithCreate(sourceFile, destFile);

            });
```

and below is the for loop which generates thread which i tried to call the code above:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= Int32.Parse(iNrOfThreads.Text); i++)
            {
                //fileName2 = fileNameSmall + i.ToString() + ".docx";
                fileName = fileNameLarge + i.ToString() + ".doc";
                fileName2 = fileNameLarge + i.ToString() + ".pdf";
                string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
                string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName2);

                // To copy a file to another location and 
                // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
                //System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

                //Thread thread = new Thread(() => GeneratePDFWithProgress(sourceFile, destFile + ".pdf"));
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => GeneratePDFWithProgressWithCreate(sourceFile, destFile));
                thread.Name = "Thread" + i.ToString();
                thread.IsBackground = true;
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
                thread.Start();              
            }
```

Comment: This might be "by design". I.e. I have a vague recollection that the Office app automation intentionally will close the application instance only when just a single document has been opened. When you open multiple document instances, then closing the automation object (which you fail to do here, but which should eventually happen anyway due to GC and the finalizer for the object) won't actually close the application. Short of finding the `Process` instance itself and closing it explicitly, I'm not aware of any way around this design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by declaring the variable local

from the original code

```
    wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

I changed it to

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordAppPrivate = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

So now it is local to the function here is the complete code for the function called with the thread i create

```
    void GeneratePDFWithProgressWithCreate(string wordFilename, string pdfFilename)        
    {       
            // Update Progress bar to see start of threads         
            UpdateProgress();
            // Setup Word Application
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordAppPrivate = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = wordAppPrivate.Documents.Open(wordFilename, false);
            wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfFilename, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
            object saveOption = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
            object originalFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat;
            object routeDocument = false;

            if (wordDocument != null) 
                ((_Document)wordDocument).Close(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);
            if (wordAppPrivate != null)
                ((_Application)wordAppPrivate).Quit(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);

            if (wordDocument != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordDocument);

            if (wordAppPrivate != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordAppPrivate);

            wordDocument = null;
            wordAppPrivate = null;
            //GC.Collect(); // force final cleanup!

            // Update progress bar to see finishing the conversion
            UpdateProgress();               
        //}
    }
```

I hope this will help others who have similar problems!

Comment: This was happening since the same variable wordApp was used in parallel, because it was declared as global. I'm glad you fixed. I think you can mark your answer as accepted, in order to let other users understand what is the solution.