# Threading a word routine to convert doc to PDF

Tags: c#, multithreading

Am new to threading and have started a 2 threads application, it runs a basic Doc to PDF conversion method. The client has Word 2003 files to convert.

However the code runs it seems to open a word instance to screen, it did open a box and progress bar before I threaded it.

Should I be handling word in a different way now?

Am trying to utlise the processor by running more than 1 thread and speed up converting 30000 doc files.

Am not looking to use any 3rd party tools, just word as from posts on the site Word is the best at conversion.

Main

```
 MyThread thr1 = new MyThread();
 MyThread thr2 = new MyThread();

 Thread tid1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thr1.Thread1));
 Thread tid2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thr2.Thread1));

 tid1.Name = "Thread 1";
 tid2.Name = "Thread 2";

 tid1.Start();
 tid2.Start();
```

Thread1 Code

```
     Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

     // C# doesn't have optional arguments so we'll need a dummy value
     object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

     // Get list of Word files in specified directory
     DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\ConvertToPDF\Docs");
     FileInfo[] wordFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.doc");

     Thread thr = Thread.CurrentThread;

     if (thr.Name == "Thread 1")
        {
        var orderedSort = wordFiles.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);
        }
     else
        {
        var orderedSort = wordFiles.OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime);
        }

     word.Visible = false;
     word.ScreenUpdating = false;

     foreach (FileInfo wordFile in wordFiles)
        {
       // Cast as Object for word Open method
       Object filename = (Object)wordFile.FullName;

      // Use the dummy value as a placeholder for optional arguments
      Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
      doc.Activate();

      object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
      object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

      // Save document into PDF Format
      doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
                ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

      object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
         ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            doc = null;
        }

        // word has to be cast to type _Application so that it will find
        // the correct Quit method.
        ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        word = null;
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, but Word doesn't run headless. Multithreading the application that opens Word isn't going to change that.

Comment: When it opens the Word document its actually opening word..before it was just a saving PDF progress box

Comment: You are *still* opening Word, you simply don't see the window. Don't do that. Using multiple threads isn't going to help you at all since the single application will have to serialize requests from the threads and may end up deadlocking. Worse, unless you really understand COM interop, you can spawn new Word instances for each file until the server runs out of memory. If you *don't* actually want the Word files, use a library to create PDF files directly. Even if you do, you still need to use a library for this

Comment: Ok I see what you mean..is there no way to open an instance of word assign it/ use it with thread 1.. ie not closing it but reusing it. And having a separate word instance and assign that to thread 2.

Comment: Have a look at my solution on converting to PDF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850434/wordapp-not-closing-in-thread-or-parallel-process/28875427#28875427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code I used in the answer on the following question:

[Wordapp not closing in Thread or Parallel process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850434/wordapp-not-closing-in-thread-or-parallel-process/28875427#28875427)

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for a way of using Word to run a few threads

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Word on the server. You're gonna have a bad time.

Use the OpenXML SDK:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

Comment: The files are all on local drive to speed up moving to PDF. Open XML started with Office 2007, the client has 2003 doc files

Comment: Then use a different library. I've used this successfully: http://www.aspose.com/.