# Thread sync for creating word documents

Tags: c#, thread-synchronization

I have a Word template file in which I replace certain tags with my data.
I tried to synchronise file creating with Parallel, but as you can see on the picture, after a while I get this File in use window.
I looked it up on the internet and I think it's because the word file isn't closing, because it was declared as global, but that solution ([Wordapp not closing in Thread or Parallel process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850434/wordapp-not-closing-in-thread-or-parallel-process/28875427#28875427)) was so different from my code and I coulnd't understand what I need to do. I am beginner with creating Word files, so I don't understand my code exactly.

Can somebody give me a potential solution for my problem?

[image]

The Word creator:

```
private static void CreateWordDocument(object filename, object SaveAs, string title, string description, string price)
        {
            
            Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
            object missing = Missing.Value;
            Word.Document myWordDoc = null;

            if (File.Exists((string)filename))
            {
                object readOnly = false;
                object isVisible = false;
                wordApp.Visible = false;
                
                myWordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
               
                
                myWordDoc.Activate();

                //find and replace
                ReplaceTextInWordDoc(wordApp, "<title>", title);
                ReplaceTextInWordDoc(wordApp, "<description>", description);
                ReplaceTextInWordDoc(wordApp, "<price>", price);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not Found!");
            }

            //Save as
            myWordDoc.SaveAs2(ref SaveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            myWordDoc.Close();
            wordApp.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("File Created!");
        }
```

Calling my method with Parallel:

```
Parallel.ForEach(gameList, (game) =>
            {
                string path = "C:\\Users\\Bence\\Desktop\\ps2\\" + game.title;
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
               
                    CreateWordDocument(@"C:\Users\Bence\Desktop\myWord\temp.docx", path + "\\" + game.title + ".docx", game.title, description, game.price);
                
                
            });
```

Comment: You might want to read [Considerations for server-side automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) - you may think that's not what you're doing but note - "All current versions of Microsoft Office were designed, tested, and configured to run as end-user products on a client workstation. They assume an interactive desktop and user profile. **They do not provide the level of reentrancy**... "

Comment: Office automation actually opens an instance of the word application. This can be rather fragile, and trying to process multiple documents in parallel will probably not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need a solution for it, but I could solve by making a copy of the template before each Paralell running of your function "CreateWordDocument", and deleting it just after.
Like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(gameList, (game) =>
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\rafael\Desktop" + @"\ps2\" + game.title;
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    File.Copy(@"C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\myWord\temp.docx", path + @"\temp.docx");
    CreateWordDocument(path + @"\temp.docx", (string)game.title, game.title, game.description, game.price);
    File.Move(@"C:\Users\rafael\Documents\" + (string)game.title + ".docx", path + @"\" + (string)game.title + ".docx");
    File.Delete(path + @"\temp.docx");
});
```

Down below in full if anyone else wanna try it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Game
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void ReplaceTextInWordDoc(Word.Application wordapp, object ToFindText, object replaceWithText)
        {
            //options
            object matchCase = false;
            object matchWholeWord = true;
            object matchWildCards = false;
            object matchSoundsLike = false;
            object matchAllWordForms = false;
            object forward = true;
            object format = false;
            object matchKashida = false;
            object matchDiacritics = false;
            object matchAlefHamza = false;
            object matchControl = false;
            object read_only = false;
            object visible = true;
            object replace = 2;
            object wrap = 1;
            //execute find and replace
            wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref ToFindText, ref matchCase,
                ref matchWholeWord, ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike,
                ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format,
                ref replaceWithText, ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
        }
        private static void CreateWordDocument(object filename, object SaveAs, string title, string description, string price)
        {

            Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
            object missing = Missing.Value;
            Word.Document myWordDoc = null;

            if (File.Exists((string)filename))
            {
                object readOnly = true;
                object isVisible = false;
                wordApp.Visible = false;

                myWordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);


                myWordDoc.Activate();

                //find and replace
                ReplaceTextInWordDoc(wordApp, "<title>", title);
                ReplaceTextInWordDoc(wordApp, "<description>", description);
                ReplaceTextInWordDoc(wordApp, "<price>", price);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not Found!");
            }

            //Save as
            myWordDoc.SaveAs2(ref SaveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            myWordDoc.Close();
            wordApp.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("File Created!");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Game> gameList = new List<Game>();
            gameList.Add(new Game { title = "counterStrile", description = "Shooter", price = "100,00" });
            gameList.Add(new Game { title = "FifaSoccer", description = "Futball", price = "120,00" });
            gameList.Add(new Game { title = "Sonic", description = "Linear", price = "90,00" });
            //foreach(var game in gameList)
            //{
            //    string path = @"C:\Users\rafael\Desktop" + @"\ps2\" + game.title;
            //    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            //    CreateWordDocument(@"C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\myWord\temp.docx", (string)game.title, game.title, game.description, game.price);
            //    File.Move(@"C:\Users\rafael\Documents\" + (string)game.title + ".docx", path +@"\" + (string)game.title + ".docx");
            //};
            Parallel.ForEach(gameList, (game) =>
            {
                string path = @"C:\Users\rafael\Desktop" + @"\ps2\" + game.title;
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                File.Copy(@"C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\myWord\temp.docx", path + @"\temp.docx");
                CreateWordDocument(path + @"\temp.docx", (string)game.title, game.title, game.description, game.price);
                File.Move(@"C:\Users\rafael\Documents\" + (string)game.title + ".docx", path + @"\" + (string)game.title + ".docx");
                File.Delete(path + @"\temp.docx");
            });
        }
    }
}
```